# web.config - Deny access to an specific folder and content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

**The objective:**

Deny access for anonymous users to an specific folder and their content on web.config file.

**The problem**

In that folder we have some folders and inside each folder we have html files,
Example:

- "Demos/beta1/index.html"
- "Demos/beta2/index.html"

If we introduce on the browser the following URL ("Demos/beta1/index.html" ) The authoritzation is not working for anonymous users.Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="Demos" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you by any chance removed AnonymousIdentification `<remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />`

Comment: No, the most interesting is that it works with other URL like "Demos/beta1"

Comment: then might be its the problem of location path...

Comment: What does it mean "of location path?" the Demos folders is located on the Content folder and the web.config is located inside the Content folder also.

Comment: just try removing the path property and then check, I am not sure about that part...

Comment: any resolution on this, I am having the same problem.  Even if I put a web.config in the directory using system.web / authorization config settings.